# CS50 pset 6 readability getting a sintax error on elif line

Tags: python, cs50

This is my code:
I can't seem to find the problem why it keeps telling me: ~/pset6/ $ python readability.py
File "readability.py", line 17
elif(index >= 16):
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I am getting very frustrated if someone can help i would really apreciate it!

```
from cs50 import get_string
import math
text = get_string("Text:").strip()
words, letters, sentences = 0, 0, 0
for i in range(len(text)):
    if (i == 0 and text[i] != '') or (i != len(text) - 1 and text[i] == '' and text[i+1] != ''):
        words += 1
        if text[i].isalpha():
            letters += 1
            if text[i] == '.' or text[i] == '?' or text[i] == '!':
               sentences += 1
               L = letters / words * 100
               S = sentences / words * 100
               index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8)
if (index < 1):
    print("Before Grade 1")
    elif(index >= 16): 
        print("Grade 16+")
        else:
            print(f"grade {index}")
```

Answer (score 1):

`elif` should be at the same indentation level as the initial `if`. You have an extra indent so you are getting an error.

Comment: Thanks can't believe that was the error, i wasted almost 1 hour finding it! Really appreciate the help

Comment: Sure thing! What IDE are you using? I'm surprised it didn't catch it for you!